# Send Image to hangout chat using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, google-api, python-requests

I want to send image from the local folder to the Hangout chat room.I am not familiar with google chat API but managed to get text sent but don't know how to send image?

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/googleworkspace/hangouts-chat-samples) contains sample code with the Google Chat API.

Comment: Please show what research you have done, where exactly you're stuck. Your question cannot be answered as it is, as it is too broad and lacks details.